# Creating OpenFeint static library for iOS

Tags: ios, openfeint, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to create a static library of Openfeint for iOS, to use it in apps with only C++ calls. When I try to run the cocos2d-x test project with that library linked, the app is going frozen with any OpenFeint call. However, if I don't create the library and I add the sources directly to the test project, it works perfectly. I'm working with SDK 5.0, Xcode 4.2 and deploying target 4.2 (I think that it doesn't really mind, because I can run it without creating the library)
Thanks, regards!

Answer (score 4):

Alternative: Use a wrapper provided on the official web to use ScoreLoop, like OpenFeint: [HERE](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/assets/9). It´s cross-plarform, work on Android, Blackberry and iOS.